# How to get the maximum info for a USB drive by looking at the debugfs output?

Tags: usb, mount

I inserted an usb into my Fedora 11 PC.
Gave a `mount` command and the output was as shown below:

```
/dev/sdc1 on /media/8d079aad-038c-4667-9186-e21bed0928d5 type ext2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=devkit)
```

Now i gave `debugfs /dev/sdc1` and the output is as shown below:

```
[root@Android04 Android-STB-Source]# debugfs /dev/sdc1
debugfs 1.41.4 (27-Jan-2009)
debugfs:  stats
Filesystem volume name:   <none>
Last mounted on:          <not available>
Filesystem UUID:          8d079aad-038c-4667-9186-e21bed0928d5
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype sparse_super large_file
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash 
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         not clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              981120
Block count:              3921916
Reserved block count:     196095
Free blocks:              3847778
Free inodes:              981101
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      957
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8176
Inode blocks per group:   511
Filesystem created:       Thu Jan  6 19:14:41 2011
Last mount time:          Thu Jan  6 19:58:09 2011
Last write time:          Tue Jan 11 16:36:05 2011
Mount count:              10
Maximum mount count:      22
Last checked:             Thu Jan  6 19:14:41 2011
Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)
Next check after:         Tue Jul  5 19:14:41 2011
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:           256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      df25de9d-4b30-4408-ab43-66f3176c4469
Directories:              4
 Group  0: block bitmap at 959, inode bitmap at 960, inode table at 961
           31290 free blocks, 8165 free inodes, 2 used directories
 Group  1: block bitmap at 33727, inode bitmap at 33728, inode table at 33729
           31296 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group  2: block bitmap at 65536, inode bitmap at 65537, inode table at 65538
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group  3: block bitmap at 99263, inode bitmap at 99264, inode table at 99265
           31296 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group  4: block bitmap at 131072, inode bitmap at 131073, inode table at 131074
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group  5: block bitmap at 164799, inode bitmap at 164800, inode table at 164801
           31296 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group  6: block bitmap at 196608, inode bitmap at 196609, inode table at 196610
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group  7: block bitmap at 230335, inode bitmap at 230336, inode table at 230337
           31296 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group  8: block bitmap at 262144, inode bitmap at 262145, inode table at 262146
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group  9: block bitmap at 295871, inode bitmap at 295872, inode table at 295873
           31296 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 10: block bitmap at 327680, inode bitmap at 327681, inode table at 327682
           29321 free blocks, 8173 free inodes, 1 used directory
 Group 11: block bitmap at 360448, inode bitmap at 360449, inode table at 360450
           32207 free blocks, 8171 free inodes, 1 used directory
 Group 12: block bitmap at 393216, inode bitmap at 393217, inode table at 393218
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 13: block bitmap at 425984, inode bitmap at 425985, inode table at 425986
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 14: block bitmap at 458752, inode bitmap at 458753, inode table at 458754
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 15: block bitmap at 491520, inode bitmap at 491521, inode table at 491522
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 16: block bitmap at 524288, inode bitmap at 524289, inode table at 524290
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 17: block bitmap at 557056, inode bitmap at 557057, inode table at 557058
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 18: block bitmap at 589824, inode bitmap at 589825, inode table at 589826
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 19: block bitmap at 622592, inode bitmap at 622593, inode table at 622594
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 20: block bitmap at 655360, inode bitmap at 655361, inode table at 655362
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 21: block bitmap at 688128, inode bitmap at 688129, inode table at 688130
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 22: block bitmap at 720896, inode bitmap at 720897, inode table at 720898
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 23: block bitmap at 753664, inode bitmap at 753665, inode table at 753666
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 24: block bitmap at 786432, inode bitmap at 786433, inode table at 786434
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 25: block bitmap at 820159, inode bitmap at 820160, inode table at 820161
           31296 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 26: block bitmap at 851968, inode bitmap at 851969, inode table at 851970
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 27: block bitmap at 885695, inode bitmap at 885696, inode table at 885697
           31296 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 28: block bitmap at 917504, inode bitmap at 917505, inode table at 917506
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 29: block bitmap at 950272, inode bitmap at 950273, inode table at 950274
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 30: block bitmap at 983040, inode bitmap at 983041, inode table at 983042
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 31: block bitmap at 1015808, inode bitmap at 1015809, inode table at 1015810
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 32: block bitmap at 1048576, inode bitmap at 1048577, inode table at 1048578
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 33: block bitmap at 1081344, inode bitmap at 1081345, inode table at 1081346
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 34: block bitmap at 1114112, inode bitmap at 1114113, inode table at 1114114
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 35: block bitmap at 1146880, inode bitmap at 1146881, inode table at 1146882
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 36: block bitmap at 1179648, inode bitmap at 1179649, inode table at 1179650
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 37: block bitmap at 1212416, inode bitmap at 1212417, inode table at 1212418
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 38: block bitmap at 1245184, inode bitmap at 1245185, inode table at 1245186
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 39: block bitmap at 1277952, inode bitmap at 1277953, inode table at 1277954
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 40: block bitmap at 1310720, inode bitmap at 1310721, inode table at 1310722
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 41: block bitmap at 1343488, inode bitmap at 1343489, inode table at 1343490
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 42: block bitmap at 1376256, inode bitmap at 1376257, inode table at 1376258
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 43: block bitmap at 1409024, inode bitmap at 1409025, inode table at 1409026
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 44: block bitmap at 1441792, inode bitmap at 1441793, inode table at 1441794
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 45: block bitmap at 1474560, inode bitmap at 1474561, inode table at 1474562
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 46: block bitmap at 1507328, inode bitmap at 1507329, inode table at 1507330
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 47: block bitmap at 1540096, inode bitmap at 1540097, inode table at 1540098
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 48: block bitmap at 1572864, inode bitmap at 1572865, inode table at 1572866
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 49: block bitmap at 1606591, inode bitmap at 1606592, inode table at 1606593
           31296 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 50: block bitmap at 1638400, inode bitmap at 1638401, inode table at 1638402
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 51: block bitmap at 1671168, inode bitmap at 1671169, inode table at 1671170
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 52: block bitmap at 1703936, inode bitmap at 1703937, inode table at 1703938
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 53: block bitmap at 1736704, inode bitmap at 1736705, inode table at 1736706
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 54: block bitmap at 1769472, inode bitmap at 1769473, inode table at 1769474
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 55: block bitmap at 1802240, inode bitmap at 1802241, inode table at 1802242
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 56: block bitmap at 1835008, inode bitmap at 1835009, inode table at 1835010
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 57: block bitmap at 1867776, inode bitmap at 1867777, inode table at 1867778
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 58: block bitmap at 1900544, inode bitmap at 1900545, inode table at 1900546
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 59: block bitmap at 1933312, inode bitmap at 1933313, inode table at 1933314
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 60: block bitmap at 1966080, inode bitmap at 1966081, inode table at 1966082
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 61: block bitmap at 1998848, inode bitmap at 1998849, inode table at 1998850
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 62: block bitmap at 2031616, inode bitmap at 2031617, inode table at 2031618
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 63: block bitmap at 2064384, inode bitmap at 2064385, inode table at 2064386
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 64: block bitmap at 2097152, inode bitmap at 2097153, inode table at 2097154
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 65: block bitmap at 2129920, inode bitmap at 2129921, inode table at 2129922
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 66: block bitmap at 2162688, inode bitmap at 2162689, inode table at 2162690
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 67: block bitmap at 2195456, inode bitmap at 2195457, inode table at 2195458
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 68: block bitmap at 2228224, inode bitmap at 2228225, inode table at 2228226
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 69: block bitmap at 2260992, inode bitmap at 2260993, inode table at 2260994
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 70: block bitmap at 2293760, inode bitmap at 2293761, inode table at 2293762
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 71: block bitmap at 2326528, inode bitmap at 2326529, inode table at 2326530
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 72: block bitmap at 2359296, inode bitmap at 2359297, inode table at 2359298
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 73: block bitmap at 2392064, inode bitmap at 2392065, inode table at 2392066
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 74: block bitmap at 2424832, inode bitmap at 2424833, inode table at 2424834
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 75: block bitmap at 2457600, inode bitmap at 2457601, inode table at 2457602
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 76: block bitmap at 2490368, inode bitmap at 2490369, inode table at 2490370
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 77: block bitmap at 2523136, inode bitmap at 2523137, inode table at 2523138
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 78: block bitmap at 2555904, inode bitmap at 2555905, inode table at 2555906
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 79: block bitmap at 2588672, inode bitmap at 2588673, inode table at 2588674
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 80: block bitmap at 2621440, inode bitmap at 2621441, inode table at 2621442
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 81: block bitmap at 2655167, inode bitmap at 2655168, inode table at 2655169
           31296 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 82: block bitmap at 2686976, inode bitmap at 2686977, inode table at 2686978
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 83: block bitmap at 2719744, inode bitmap at 2719745, inode table at 2719746
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 84: block bitmap at 2752512, inode bitmap at 2752513, inode table at 2752514
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 85: block bitmap at 2785280, inode bitmap at 2785281, inode table at 2785282
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 86: block bitmap at 2818048, inode bitmap at 2818049, inode table at 2818050
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 87: block bitmap at 2850816, inode bitmap at 2850817, inode table at 2850818
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 88: block bitmap at 2883584, inode bitmap at 2883585, inode table at 2883586
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 89: block bitmap at 2916352, inode bitmap at 2916353, inode table at 2916354
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 90: block bitmap at 2949120, inode bitmap at 2949121, inode table at 2949122
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 91: block bitmap at 2981888, inode bitmap at 2981889, inode table at 2981890
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 92: block bitmap at 3014656, inode bitmap at 3014657, inode table at 3014658
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 93: block bitmap at 3047424, inode bitmap at 3047425, inode table at 3047426
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 94: block bitmap at 3080192, inode bitmap at 3080193, inode table at 3080194
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 95: block bitmap at 3112960, inode bitmap at 3112961, inode table at 3112962
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 96: block bitmap at 3145728, inode bitmap at 3145729, inode table at 3145730
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 97: block bitmap at 3178496, inode bitmap at 3178497, inode table at 3178498
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 98: block bitmap at 3211264, inode bitmap at 3211265, inode table at 3211266
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 99: block bitmap at 3244032, inode bitmap at 3244033, inode table at 3244034
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 100: block bitmap at 3276800, inode bitmap at 3276801, inode table at 3276802
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 101: block bitmap at 3309568, inode bitmap at 3309569, inode table at 3309570
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 102: block bitmap at 3342336, inode bitmap at 3342337, inode table at 3342338
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 103: block bitmap at 3375104, inode bitmap at 3375105, inode table at 3375106
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 104: block bitmap at 3407872, inode bitmap at 3407873, inode table at 3407874
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 105: block bitmap at 3440640, inode bitmap at 3440641, inode table at 3440642
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 106: block bitmap at 3473408, inode bitmap at 3473409, inode table at 3473410
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 107: block bitmap at 3506176, inode bitmap at 3506177, inode table at 3506178
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 108: block bitmap at 3538944, inode bitmap at 3538945, inode table at 3538946
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 109: block bitmap at 3571712, inode bitmap at 3571713, inode table at 3571714
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 110: block bitmap at 3604480, inode bitmap at 3604481, inode table at 3604482
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 111: block bitmap at 3637248, inode bitmap at 3637249, inode table at 3637250
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 112: block bitmap at 3670016, inode bitmap at 3670017, inode table at 3670018
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 113: block bitmap at 3702784, inode bitmap at 3702785, inode table at 3702786
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 114: block bitmap at 3735552, inode bitmap at 3735553, inode table at 3735554
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 115: block bitmap at 3768320, inode bitmap at 3768321, inode table at 3768322
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 116: block bitmap at 3801088, inode bitmap at 3801089, inode table at 3801090
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 117: block bitmap at 3833856, inode bitmap at 3833857, inode table at 3833858
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 118: block bitmap at 3866624, inode bitmap at 3866625, inode table at 3866626
           32255 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
 Group 119: block bitmap at 3899392, inode bitmap at 3899393, inode table at 3899394
           22011 free blocks, 8176 free inodes, 0 used directories
```

I would like to get the maximum info (info i can get from giving `lspci`) from this printed info. I would like to know how i can do that.

What i have in my mind is like, I give a command :

```
dd bs=<some size> skip=<some size> count=1 if=/dev/sdc1 | od -Ax -tx1z -v
```

And this shows the needed details. Basically i need to get the USB hardware details form the filesystem.

Please suggest on this idea, or if you have some other idea for doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the hardware details are integrated into the file-system, they're maintained by the USB controller

Answer (score 1):

check with `lsusb`

also dmesg after plugging the device